# obtain type of road on which my vehicle currently is on using the GPS obtained latitude and longitude

Tags: gps, openstreetmap

I'm now working on a project to know if vehicles are over-speeding based on the roads speed limits.for this,**we need to get the type** (highway,school road etc) **of road on which my vehicle currently is on using the GPS obtained latitude and longitude**.how can we obtain this from OSM.We are new to this ,so need a good description on this. Better if you can provide us the codes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [overpass-turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/) to obtain this kind of data from OSM. [Documentation is here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide). This example query will give you all roads in specified polygon

```
way(50.745,7.17,50.75,7.18)[highway];
(._;>;);
out;
```

Keep in mind that this is free service but has it's usage conditions. If you're planning making a lot of queries you should think about your own service or database...

Comment: thank you,for your help.We are not going to make too much queries but Just needed the types of roads.

Comment: The example shows drinking water locations.Can you give the codes for accessing the different types of roads.Example : Highway,Subway etc..

Comment: I gave you site and a snipppet of code to paste it into this site. You have also link to documentation where you have explained with examples how to build a queries...  I was wondering you can handle some ctrl+c, ctrl+v... but - no problem I could paste it for you. (http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/nrV)

Comment: thank you .and sorry if i caused any overhead.Thanks a lot

Comment: what is the uses of maxspeed key in openstreetmap.Can we retrive the maximum allowed speed (approx.) on a road using maxspeed key.As we need to do a project on that can you tell us how exactly can we do that.provides if any codes available with you.and thank you

Comment: If this tag is present in data you'll get it from this query

Comment: Can we retrive the data from overpass-turbo using arduino or through web service i.e we need to get it nwith out entering the latitude and longitude manually.is that possible?